# Can't reference proprety name with '-' Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, properties

This is the output when I `console.log` my object using `console.log(category)`.

```
{ _id: 5b723aa57bab2a0b9a0d1429,
updatedBy: 5b62743ac154c5669e9259d0,
updatedAt: 2018-08-14T09:25:20.050Z,
createdBy: 5b62743ac154c5669e9259d0,
createdAt: 2018-08-14T02:12:53.705Z,
name: 'Community Engagement',
__v: 0,
'dialogflow-agent': '8df9fab841554e8badfe2f66c74e08f3' }
```

But strangely when I `console.log(category["dialogflow-agent"])` it gives me `undefined`

Does anyone know how to access the property `dialogflow-agent`?

**UPDATE:**

Output of JSON.stringify(category) is:

`{"_id":"5b6ac11920bea9751e2847e3","updatedBy":"5b62743ac154c5669e9259d0","updatedAt":"2018-08-14T09:03:54.638Z","createdBy":"5b62743ac154c5669e9259d0","createdAt":"2018-08-08T10:08:25.917Z","name":"Awards and Scholarships","__v":0,"dialogflow-agent":"26d927f3f627496fbacc08ac16af898f"}`

Comment: What does `console.log(object['_id'])` print? Your code seems correct to me.

Comment: That's probably response of an async request! What does `console.log(typeof object)` log?

Comment: Is your object actually named `object`?

Comment: @undefined - Except this is Node.js's `console.log` output, which isn't dynamic like a browser's.

Comment: @31piy it prints the _id correctly 5b6ac11920bea9751e2847e3
@undefined What do you mean? when I console.log my object all data appears, the promise is resolved.
@Shilly no it is called `category` will change it in the question!

Comment: The way you're accessing it is correct, which means something isn't quite as it seems from your question. Use a debugger to step through the code and examine the object when you're paused on that `console.log`. For us to help you, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. It might also be useful to see the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(category))`, although the Node.js representation you've shown is fairly clear.

Comment: If the object is valid ( everything but _v being a string ) and the names are correct, category["dialogflow-agent"] should work. SO the problem is in surrounding code we haven't seen yet.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry I'll read the link and update my question to help you further. I updated my question with the output of JSON.stringify(category)

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't help you with this, however much we want to (and I do, I'm really curious what's going on). :-) If the object is really as the JSON you've added suggests, [what you're doing works](http://jsfiddle.net/kh9sdz5n/). So, again, there's something going on that isn't represented in the question. It'll require debugging in your real situation, which we can't do from here. But again, the way you're trying to access that property is correct and **does** work if the object has that property. So don't worry about that part, you're doing it right.

Comment: Yup, @T.J.Crowder true I tested in a new file and the way I'm accessing the property is working, I'll try to debug and will let you know if I reach the reason. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since you mention a promise, are you Sure that you're not trying to log before the promise resolves? As you can see in this mockup, the shown code is correct. http://jsfiddle.net/ao2g3vhL/2/ so try finding the root cause.

Comment: @Shilly I am retrieving the object `category` from the DB using `await Category.findById(categoryId).exec();` in an `async` function. I am very sorry if I'm not giving you enough info, but I don't really know now what might be useful to share with u so you can help me, I am trying to investigate as much as I can :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was missing in the question is that `Category` is a mongoose schema, the attributes in this schema was missing `dialogflow-agent`.

```
let categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    'dialogflow-agent': String,    // This line was missing.
});
```

Thank you @Shilly and @T.J.Crowder for helping, and sorry for the missing info in the question. but for whoever is facing this, please check your schema.

Comment: Wow. They must be using a Proxy to intercept...no, then `JSON.stringify` would have been affected as well. Same if it's a getter. How very odd.

Comment: I totally agree it is so weird, but they obviously hide the properties when you access them through getters, but not when you print the whole object (instance). so when we stringify the whole object it doesn't hide the properties you didn't define, should it be reported to mongoose tho? :D isn't it very weird behavior?

Comment: The thing is, I don't even know how they'd do that, either a Proxy nor a simple getter would behave that way with `JSON.stringify`. I'd definitely put together an [mcve] and raise an issue on it.

Comment: That would be great, will you please tag me or send the link here when you do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "I'd definitely put together..." means "If I were in your position, I'd definitely put together..." I'm not going to do it (not least because I don't use Mongoose). I'm suggesting that *you* do it.

Comment: Oh ok sorry misunderstood, I'll do that now. Thanks